# What happened to Bruce Wayne in Green Lantern Vol. 4?

Tags: dc, batman, green-lantern, blackest-night

I am currently reading Green Lantern Vol. 4, and something is unclear to me.

In Sinestro Corps War, a yellow ring finds Bruce Wayne. Later, in Blackest Night, Flash and Hal find Bruce Wayne's grave dug up, and his skull has been stolen. My question is when did Batman find time to die?

Comment: When did Batman found time to die? It's a master plan I tell you!

Comment: He will come back, every comic character does.

Comment: Seems to be a [lot of things going on](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100211171649AA1FBLl) at the same time in that crossover. Hal and Barry realize that because Black Lantern Batman was a fake, Bruce Wayne is still alive somewhere (which ties in with "The Return of Bruce Wayne"). I hope that sheds some light about the black lantern/dead Bruce. Still, I can't explain a yellow lantern Batman + a Black lantern one at the same time.

Answer (score 5):

Bruce didn't keep the Yellow Lantern ring. Between then and *Blackest Night* came *Final Crisis*, in which Batman is struck by Darkseid's Omega Effect eye-beams. Everyone presumes he is dead after this; however, the beams did not kill him; they sent him to the past, and charged him such that he would eventually be jumped back to the present (part of a plan that was foiled by the Justice League and Batman's heirs: Dick Grayson, Tim Drake, and Damian Wayne).